# How can I get GoLand to build everything?

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to do the equivalent of `go build ./...` in GoLand, so I can see all the errors in the IDE in one go? I have modified some widely used structs and I want to find all the places I need to change.

I have tried a package build at the top of my tree but that "succeeds" very quickly whereas build ./... in the same directory fails as expected.

I also tried a directory build with ./... as a tool argument but that gives an error

```
can't load package: package -o: cannot find package "-o" in any of:
```

which I assume is because whatever GoLand is putting around the configuration is not compatible with that argument.

Comment: With JetBrains IDEs most common refactoring tasks are auto-propagated. What is the exact change? Personally, I would just Cmd+Shift+F7 to look up all usages. And if you want to do a `go build` with any parameters you can add custom configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nestor-sokil, mentioned above, if you perform the refactoring operations via the IDE tools, `Refactor | Refactor This...`, then the IDE manages all the changes automatically for you. If you do find places where this doesn't happen or a refactoring tool is missing, you can open an issue on the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go).

That being said, you can follow the instructions below to configure the IDE to run `go build ./...` for you. The caveat is that it may show problems that are not normally encountered in operations as the command is unaware of build tags, multiple `main()` function containing files in the same directory, and so on.

You can create an external tool via `Settings/Preferences | Tools | External Tools` and configure like this:

[image: External tool configuration]

You can then go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` and search for the name of the tool and assign it a shortcut to execute it more conveniently.